# Distributing a cell in MySQL to multiple records

Tags: mysql

My schema is briefly as such:

```
date,value1,value2,value3
```

And what I want to do is, everytime a record that has `value1 > 0`, I want to distribute that among the week (a defined window, not just previous 7 days, etc.) containing that value, thus:

read record:

```
2020-02-10, 7, x, y
```

pre-update records:

```
2020-02-09,0,x,y
2020-02-10,7,x,y
2020-02-11,0,x,y
2020-02-12,0,x,y
2020-02-13,0,x,y
2020-02-14,0,x,y
2020-02-15,0,x,y
```

updated records:

```
2020-02-09,1,x,y
2020-02-10,1,x,y
2020-02-11,1,x,y
2020-02-12,1,x,y
2020-02-13,1,x,y
2020-02-14,1,x,y
2020-02-15,1,x,y
```

I believe subqueries using a SUM() function is the answer, but having difficulty thinking this out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: is `value1` an integer? or what should happen if someone enters a number that is not divisible by `7`?,   [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) seems to be a nice feature for this....

Comment: There are two cases actually. One will be an integer, and thus I would like to maintain those remaining values (in any way really). The value that's a double, same but in regards to precision. Edit - Also thanks, looking into this trigger for now!

Comment: start creating a trigger, see docs, and edit your question with this info if you need more info.... 

Comment: A trigger isn't allowed to modify the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `YEARWEEK()` function to group all the rows with the same week. You can use this to sum the value across the week, and join with all the rows.

```
UPDATE yourTable AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT YEARWEEK(date) AS week, SUM(value1) AS weeksum
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY week
) AS t2 ON YEARWEEK(t1.date) = t2.week
SET t1.value1 = t2.weeksum/7
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte1 AS 
(
SELECT date - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(date) - 1 DAY date,
       SUM(value1) value1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(value2) value2,
       GROUP_CONCAT(value3) value3
FROM test
GROUP BY 1
),
cte2 AS 
(
SELECT date - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(date) - 1 DAY date
FROM cte1
UNION ALL 
SELECT date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
FROM cte2
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date) != 7
)
SELECT cte2.date,
       cte1.value1 / 7 value1,
       cte1.value2,
       cte1.value3
FROM cte2
JOIN cte1 ON cte2.date - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(cte2.date) - 1 DAY = cte1.date;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d5dcca391e8633e30d1b035e2013973)

The query does not take into account the year of a value.